# How to input Multiple Data in one EditText separated only by a comma?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to create a simple application on Android Studio that can compute the Mean or the Average of the data. The thing is I will only use one EditText to input Multiple set of data.

[This is my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZVF4.png)

So in the picture shown above when I click the result button the average of the numbers that I input in the edittext will be display to the MeanTextView.
I do have my codes to compute for the Mean or the average. Here is my code:

```
public static double mean(double[] m){
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<m.length; i++){
sum + = m[i];
}
return sum / m.length;
}
```

So how can I input Multiple set of data in one EditText separated only by a comma that I can use to compute for the average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of **android.text.TextUtils**

for eg:

```
double[] doubleList = new double[2];
doubleList[1] = 1221312312;
doubleList[2] = 1231231231;

List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
intList.add(1);
intList.add(2);

List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("2");
stringList.add("3");

final String doubleSeparateCommaString =
  android.text.TextUtils.join(",", new double[][] { doubleList });

final String intSeparatedCommaString = android.text.TextUtils.join(",", intList);

final String stringSeparatedCommaString =  android.text.TextUtils.join(",", stringList);
```

hoping it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

First split the string to stringArray like

```
String[] m= text.split(",") ;
```

Then sum it

```
for (int i = 0; i<m.length; i++){
sum + = Integer.parseInt(m[i]);
}
```